# When user logged in, cart not updated price when options are selected in magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, checkout

When a user is logged in and adds an item to cart and selects the product options on the cart page, the price is updated according to the product's options.

But, when it goes onto the checkout page it shows only the basic price of the product instead of the updated value.

This only occurs when the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in it works properly.

Comment: Is the problem occuring if you use the default Magento theme?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having any session problems? have you tried cleaning your sessions, caches and index? try using the sessions on the database to, theses steps have solved this problem for me once.

ps: don't forget to activate the cron job, it avoids some issues liek that